# Dependency problem with linux-image-server, linux-image and linux-headers

Tags: boot, dependencies

I had a /boot full problem but now have lots of space in /boot.  But now I can´t do `apt-get autoremove` or `apt-get -f install` or anything else.   It seems the headers are not in /boot and kept upgrading while the Linux-image did not.  What should I try next?

I also tried `apt-get dist-upgrade` and this also fails because of the same dependency problem.

Output of `ls /var/cache/apt/archives` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10343958/).

```
root@ethan:/boot# apt-get clean
root@ethan:/boot# apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
root@ethan:/boot# apt-get install linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.76.90) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.76.90) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.69.82) but 3.2.0.76.90 is to be installed
                Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.69.82) but 3.2.0.76.90 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@ethan:/boot# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-61 linux-headers-3.2.0-64 linux-headers-3.2.0-67
  linux-headers-3.2.0-61-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-64-generic
  linux-headers-3.2.0-67-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 158 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,724 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://ai.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-server amd64 3.2.0.76.90 [1,724 B]
Fetched 1,724 B in 0s (2,544 B/s)       
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.69.82); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.76.90.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.69.82); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.76.90.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: It gets the same dependency problem and fails.

Comment: The second one returns nothing.  Here is link:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10343958/

Comment: Still not working.  Latest at:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10372772/

Comment: Should I remove the .deb, lock, and partial?

Comment: So I tried removing the .deb, lock, and partial directory and it still fails. They all come back.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10372847/

Comment: could you provide the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: Nothing. Empty. Zilch.

Comment: Still not working.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10374432/         I think with dpkg once or something.

Comment: Still not making it.   http://paste.ubuntu.com/10376010/

Comment: That did not work but I added a little "*" before each ¨.¨ and that seemed to work!  Now doing apt-get upgrade and it is working like it has not in some time.  Says it has an hour to go. I think we made it!

Comment: Do you think automatic upgrades of these packages will not work any more?  If I do a dist-upgrade then they should, right?

Comment: Please see answer:  I've deleted all my comments to keep things uncluttered here.  Please do the same so that the next user that has the same problem is not overwhelmed by a huge amount of clutter neither!  **;-)**

Comment: Side-note: You are __never__ going to need `linux-headers` __unless__ you want to compile your own kernel OR you want to compile a project which *uses* kernel "features". Why so many people always keep claiming they *have* to be installed with every new kernel is beyond me. Perhaps due to an old myth...? --- Everything you need will be in `linux-image` resp. in `linux-image-extra` (the latter being required when using some non-standard hardware). And you're settled.

Answer (score 6):

Do a:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
```

then a:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo apt-get download linux-server linux-image-server linux-headers-server
```

As there seems to be a discrepency between the versions of `linux-server` (= 3.2.0.69.82) and `linux-image-server` (= 3.2.0.76.90)  install the packages using:

```
sudo dpkg --install --force-all linux-server* linux-image-server* linux-headers-server*
```

As these `.deb` files were downloaded using `apt-get` and just forced to install with `dpkg` they should not break the automatic updates in the future...

Comment: Is there something that didn't work?  Why the down-vote?

Comment: They do not understand the genius.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. I spent 3 hours looking for a solution. One small note, "download" puts files in the current directory, so it's a little misleading to cd to archives after calling apt-get download. Anyway, here's the error that you fixed for me :  linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.91.105); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.53.63.

Comment: @DAB: you're welcome.  You've got enough rep to [edit] my answer and make it even better!  Go ahead!  **;-)**

Comment: @DAB: Thank you! (and: *facepalm* that I didn't see this, but someone just downvoted at the time without leaving a comment)

Comment: I've just tested this and it works great. Thank you & upvoted.